# Error trying to POST request from react to nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to post a new object to my mongodb collection which is handled on my backend server, but the values from my request body are not passed to it.

I can guarantee that the object is created. The problem is that all the object values are empty.

I also guarantee that the nodejs code works correctly. The first thing I did was create a web application just using nodeJS and from that page I can create a new object normally.
But now I'm creating a frontend page using react and I'm not sure why my frontend page's post request doesn't work as intended

react code:

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name:nome,
        cnpj:cnpj,
        email:email,
        number:telefone,
        seguradora:[seguradora],
        index:765756
      })
  };
    try{
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/corretoras',requestOptions)
      const data = await response.json()
      console.log(data)
      console.log(requestOptions.body)
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log('error trying to post',error)
    }
  };
```

nodeJS code:

```
router.post('/',async(req,res)=>{       

    const lastIndex = await Corretora.find().sort({index:-1}).limit(1).index

    const corretora = new Corretora({        
        name:req.body.name,
        cnpj: req.body.cnpj,
        email:req.body.email,
        number:req.body.number,
        seguradora:req.body.seguradora,
        index: lastIndex
    })

    try{
        const novaCorretora = await corretora.save()
        res.redirect('corretoras/'+novaCorretora.id)

    }
    catch{
        renderNewPage(res,corretora,true)
    }
})
```

console log from react code:
[image: console log from react code]

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue. I didn't type app.use(express.json()) in my server.js